# Does polling of a USB keyboard normally slow down if not used?

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard

The fastest USB keyboards I can find use USB 2.0 with 1000 Hz polling.

If I just watch a movie and don't touch this keyboard for hours, does the back-and-forth
USB communication really continue to repeat every ms? Or will I normally enter some sort of USB sleep state (e.g., 1 Hz polling)?

[My understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)) is that, every ms, the PC should start things with an IN request, the keyboard should then send a DATA response (saying "no keys have been pressed"), and the PC should then send an ACK response.

So, I ask this question because that all seems wasteful...but maybe it's no big deal.

(This question is about normal Windows PCs, but I'm curious about Android devices as well. By the way, I think [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) keyboards don't have any back-and-forth communication through the PS/2 cable if the keyboard is not touched, but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Re *"PS/2 keyboards don't have any back-and-forth communication"*: Correct. Unless Num Lock, Caps Lock, etc. is pressed on another keyboard (then some commands for [setting the LEDs](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/08/29/controlling-leds-on-ps-2-keyboards/) will be send to all keyboards, incl. the PS/2 keyboard, and ACK bytes will be send by the PS/2 keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

> Does polling of a USB keyboard normally slow down if not used

No, the system can't tell when the keyboard is *"not used"* ahead of time.
You, the user, know that you're not using the keyboard, but the system cannot detect your intentions.

Polling of devices on the USB bus is required in order to guarantee consistent and timely servicing of all connected devices.
Event-driven schemes (e.g. using interrupts) require more-complex adaptive work-arounds to avoid starvation of low-priority or low-activity devices.

> ... does the back-and-forth USB communication really continue to repeat every ms?

Yes, that is the definition of the USB protocol for bi-directional communication on a shared medium.

> or will I normally enter some sort of USB sleep state (e.g., 1 Hz polling)?

No.
There's no penalty to poll if the bus would otherwise be idle.
An adaptive-rate polling could be implemented with increased complexity as well as the response time would suffer accordingly.

Note that this polling is typically performed primarily by the host USB controller, and not by the USB host's CPU.
This polling can have minimal impact or load on the PC processor or OS.

---

USB is a standard that is implemented in hardware and software.  The OS software side of the implementation is expected to be similar for any OS, including Windows and Android.

For instance, the polling rate of the USB device is specified by the device itself, and is not a decision by the host OS.
This polling rate is specified in the [Endpoint Descriptor](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#EndpointDescriptors), and can range from "1ms for low/full speed devices and 125us for high speed devices."

---

> I think PS/2 keyboards don't have any back-and-forth communication through the PS/2 cable if the keyboard is not touched

A PS/2 interface uses a clock line to negotiate the direction of the half-duplex communication, whereas USB is a shared, half-duplex bus that relies on a master-slave temporal protocol.
A PS/2 device can transmit at any time unless the PC host drives the clock line low, which forces the PS/2 device to stop transmitting.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable.  But, to be clear on your final point, the PS/2 clock and data lines stay at DC levels for hours while I watch the movie, right?  This is in contrast to the USB data lines which show the complicated bit pattern I described every ms.

Comment: Yes, the PS/2 link is only active when information is actually transferred.

Answer (score 1):

> If I just watch a movie and don't touch this keyboard for hours, does
> the back-and-forth USB communication really continue to repeat every
> ms? or will I normally enter some sort of USB sleep state (e.g., 1 Hz
> polling)?
>
> every ms, the PC should start things with an IN request

Actually, "communication" does not really occur on every ms. But it is true that Low-Speed USB hosts continuously pulse the bus with "keep-alive" on every ms. This is called "USB Frames". So no actual communication occurs here.

The "communication" occurs only when the host sends a polling (IN) request, as you rightfully noted. The normal polling rate for Windows is 8 ms, once per 8 frames, but it depends. If a proprietary driver is used, as "gaming keyboard", as you said, polling may happen on every 1 ms.

Yes, it is a wasteful process, true. That's why most portable devices employ power saving technique. Instead of slowing down the polling rate, they use the standard USB_SUSPEND function. If their internal algorithm determines that no new information is coming out of keyboard or mouse, the host will selectively suspend each HID (human-interface-device). Entry latency into SUSPEND state is 8 ms. If I recall correctly, the inactivity time-out is ~200 ms, after which the USB wires enter SUSPEND state, no toggling.

When you touch a keyboard or mouse, they will generate "Wake-UP" event, and the host will RESUME USB traffic and communication polling. Yes, this RESUME takes a longer time than usual polling, 15-20-50 ms, and even longer if the entire system falls asleep to some degree, so users might become frustrated with "keyboard lag". But this actively-managed suspend functionality does save the battery life.

If you just watch a movie on a desktop PC, power consumption is of lesser concern, and it is likely that polling of your keyboard never stops, although there could be configuration settings that enable more aggressive power savings.

Unlike USB, the PS/2 interface can actively generate communication traffic from keyboard/mouse side, so the interface can stay inactive without polling from host.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that most USB keyboards enter the suspend state just 200 ms after the last key press, so I'm confused.  I know you weren't certain about this exact number, but for a gaming keyboard, I'm thinking now that the host would trigger the suspend state maybe after a few minutes (instead of 200 ms) and the keyboard then must obey.  Even for a normal non-gaming keyboard, 200 ms seems short - Could you clarify this more?

Comment: @bobuhito, no, this kind of agressive power management of USB keyboards and touchpads can be found only in tablets. It is not about "most keyboards", it is about most low-powered thin mobile devices.